# Xpath is correct but no result after scraping

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl all the name of the cities of the following web:
https://www.zomato.com/directory.

I have tried to used the following xpath.

```
python
#1st approach:
def parse(self,response):
    cities_name = response.xpath('//div//h2//a/text()').extract_first()
    items['cities_name'] = cities_name
    yield items 
 #2nd approach:

def parse(self,response):
 for city in response.xpath("//div[@class='col-l-5 col-s-8 item pt0 pb5 
   ml0']"):
        l = ItemLoader(item = CountryItem(),selector = city)
        l.add_xpath("cities_name",".//h2//a/text()")
        yield l.load_item()
        yield city
```

Actual result: Crawl 0 pages and scrape 0 items
Expected: Adelaide, Ballarat etc

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note:
Your xpath is a bit too specific. Css classes in html don't always have reliable order. `class1 class2` could end up being `class2 class1` or even have some broken syntax involved like trailing spaces: `class1 class2`.

When you direct match your xpath to `[@class="class1 class2"]` there's a high chance that it will fail. Instead you should try to use `contains` function.

Second:
You have a tiny error in your `cities_name` xpath. In html body its a>h2>text and in your code it's reversed `h2>a>text`

So that being said I managed to get it working with these css and xpath selectors:

```
$ parsel "https://www.zomato.com/directory"                                                                           
> p.mb10>a>h2::text +first                                                                                            
Adelaide
> p.mb10>a>h2::text +len                                                                                              
736
> -xpath                                                                                                              
switched to xpath
> //p[contains(@class,"mb10")]/a/h2/text() +first                                                                     
Adelaide
> //p[contains(@class,"mb10")]/a/h2/text() +len                                                                       
736
```

parselcli - https://github.com/Granitosaurus/parsel-cli

Comment: //p[contains(@class,"mb10")]/a/h2/text() +first  is the whole xpath?

Comment: no, the `+first` bit is `parselcli` processor syntax - prints only first results. The xpath is everything untill that bit: `//p[contains(@class,"mb10")]/a/h2/text()`

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong XPath:

```
def parse(self,response):
 for city_node in response.xpath("//h2"):
        l = ItemLoader(item = CountryItem(), selector = city_node)
        l.add_xpath("city_name", ".//a/text()")
        yield l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you are not getting any result from that page is because the html elements of that site are not well-formed. You can get the results using `html5lib` parser. I tried with different parsers but the one I just mentioned did the trick. The following is how you can do it. I used css selector, though.

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class ZomatoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "zomato"

    start_urls= ['https://www.zomato.com/directory']

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
        for item in soup.select(".row h2 > a"):
            yield {"name":item.text}
```

Comment: Do I need to set anything in item.py?

Comment: Nothing at all. Just run as it is.

Comment: It works! I am not familiar with html..how do i know if it is well-formed? caz when i pass those xpath in the web it works fine..

Comment: When you see that the content you look for are available in page source but your parser can't dig them out then you can try alternatively with these parsers `html.parser`, `lxml` and `html5lib` to check which one is working in that case. I'm not that familiar with html either so I try with the method I described above. Thanks.